# iTunes Connect Add New Version

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

So I'm trying to add a new version to my app, I have done this many times before with no problem.

Two days ago I was trying to create new version on one of my apps, but the pop up when you select (My App -> New Version -> iOS) to add a new version, does not appear.

I thought it might be an javascript error or css error, it does not show any error, I don't see any licensing agreement I have to agree to or anything else.

Has anyone ever gotten this problem, its getting very annoying since I have to release my app.

Answer (score 0):

It's weird, Look I have the option there:

[image]

Comment: I have the option also but when I click on the '+' it asks me if I want to add a new iOS version and when I click iOS (to add a new iOS version), nothing happens. A pop up suppose to show where I write the version number I want to add but this popup never shows.

And I know my browser isn't blocking it, I clear all my browsing data, tried it on another computer but nothing.

Comment: Oh I get it. The popup is not showing to me either. I tried in two different browser.

Comment: Gonna give them I call today, this has been going on for 3 days I think.

Comment: For anyone else that runs into this post, its a know iTunes Connect bug and is being work on. There is a work around, just add display: block !important"  in button css, credit to JediRhetoric who posted this work around on the apple forum.

Answer (score 0):

To everyone that is having this problem, Apple is aware of the problem and is working on a fix. There is a work around for the time being.

Just add "display: block !important" in anchor tag of the links its css.

This should make the button work.